# C# How to move mouse(cursor) position while its hidden...?

Tags: c#, hook, global

My cursor.position function works, but when the cursor is focused in a window and hidden ( for example in a game when the cursor hides itself ) it doesn't move...
Any solution?
My code:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + Xvariable, Cursor.Position.Y + Yvariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this one

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

    public static void Move(int xDelta, int yDelta)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xDelta, yDelta, 0, 0);
    }
```

Usage `Move(830, 160);`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31514213/mouse-move-in-game-window-by-outer-c-sharp-code)